# Updating specific cell with Ruby Spreadsheet

Tags: ruby

I'm using the gem "spreadsheet" I'm trying to update a specific cell such as row(0).column(4) to a new value. I was able to get something going by using the insert method but that moves what is already in the cell to the right one cell.

I have tried:

```
book.worksheet(0).row(0).column(0).update "Payable"
```

But that column method doesn't exist. I'm probably missing something specific, but looking through the documentation on the spreadsheet github page, I'm clearly just missing something.

Comment: Are you talking about the "spreadsheet" gem? It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Yes I am, sorry I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'spreadsheet'

book = Spreadsheet.open './spreadsheet.xls'
sheet = book.worksheet 0
sheet.rows[0][0] = 'hello'
             #^--- column
book.write './spreadsheet-output.xls'
```

See Modifying an Existing Document here:

https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md#modifying-an-existing-document

This also works for me:

```
sheet = book.worksheet 0
sheet[1,0] = 'goodbye'
#row--^ ^--column
```

As does this:

```
book.worksheet(0).row(2)[0] = 'mars'
                        #^----column
```

Comment: Ah I kept using row and not ROWS blah. Thanks!